# FOSRestBundle doesn't load routes

Tags: symfony, routes, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to make a REST API using  FOSRestBundle and I'm getting some errors due to routing. This is how I test the routes. With this code in `routing.yml` I get this error:

1st test:

**routing.yml**

```
device_id_api:
    type: rest
    path: /device/{imei}/getid
    resource: "Device\DeviceBundle\Controller\DeviceRestController"
```

**Error**

> FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource
>   "/var/www/html/src/Device/DeviceBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
>   from "/var/www/html/app/config/routing.yml". (The routing
>   file
>   "/var/www/html/src/Device/DeviceBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
>   must not specify both the "resource" key and the "path" key for
>   "device_id_api". Choose between an import and a route definition.)

2nd test:

**`routing.yml**

```
device_id_api:
    type: rest
    prefix: /device/{imei}/getid
    resource: "TaxiBooking\Device\DeviceBundle\Controller\DeviceRestController"
```

**Error**

> No route found for "GET /device/2147483647/getid"

What is wrong on that routes? I clear the cache several times and the error remains. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix `/device/{imei}/getid` is exactly that, a prefix.

The actions in your controller like (for, example) `getUsersAction` will then be added to this prefix to create paths like `/device/{imei}/getid/users [GET]`.

It's all explained in the [docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md) minus your usage of the prefix, but that just means that it added to the start of the path auto-generated by the RoutingLoader.